# How to rework acceleration formula for double pendulum with mouse interaction

Tags: java, processing, physics

I need to make the mousePressed() function move the entire pendulum within the bounds of its length (r1 and r2 = 200). Lines 32-44 need to change based on the mousePressed function

I have code for a single pendulum that uses PGraphics with a function that works the way i want it to. It uses the length of the pendulum as the maximum displacement for the ball at the end. I need to translate this into a double pendulum that accounts for two lengths instead of one.After running the program for a while the line traced is bound in a circle with a radius being the sum of the r variable (400)

```
void drag() {
// If we are draging the ball, we calculate the angle between the 
// pendulum origin and mouse position
// we assign that angle to the pendulum
if (dragging) {
  PVector diff = PVector.sub(origin, new PVector(mouseX, mouseY));      // Difference between 2 points
  angle = atan2(-1*diff.y, diff.x) - radians(90);                      // Angle relative to vertical axis
}
```

}
}

```
float r1 = 200;
float r2 = 200;
float m1 = 40;
float m2 = 40;
float a1 = PI/2;
float a2 = PI/2;
float a1_v = 0;
float a2_v = 0;
float g = 1;

float px2 = -1;
float py2 = -1;
float cx, cy;

PGraphics canvas;

void setup() {
  size(1024, 768);
  cx = width/2;
  cy = 200;
  canvas = createGraphics(width, height);
  canvas.beginDraw();
  canvas.background(255);
  canvas.endDraw();
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  imageMode(CORNER);
  image(canvas, 0, 0, width, height);

  float num1 = -g * (2 * m1 + m2) * sin(a1);
  float num2 = -m2 * g * sin(a1-2*a2);
  float num3 = -2*sin(a1-a2)*m2;
  float num4 = a2_v*a2_v*r2+a1_v*a1_v*r1*cos(a1-a2);
  float den = r1 * (2*m1+m2-m2*cos(2*a1-2*a2));
  float a1_a = (num1 + num2 + num3*num4) / den;

  num1 = 2 * sin(a1-a2);
  num2 = (a1_v*a1_v*r1*(m1+m2));
  num3 = g * (m1 + m2) * cos(a1);
  num4 = a2_v*a2_v*r2*m2*cos(a1-a2);
  den = r2 * (2*m1+m2-m2*cos(2*a1-2*a2));
  float a2_a = (num1*(num2+num3+num4)) / den;

  translate(cx, cy);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(2);

  float x1 = r1 * sin(a1);
  float y1 = r1 * cos(a1);

  float x2 = 0;
  float y2 = 0;

  if(mousePressed){
    x2 = mouseX - cx;
    y2 = mouseY - cy;
  }else{
    x2 = x1 + r2 * sin(a2);
    y2 = y1 + r2 * cos(a2);  
  }

  line(0, 0, x1, y1);
  fill(0);
  ellipse(x1, y1, m1, m1);

  line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  fill(0);
  ellipse(x2, y2, m2, m2);

  a1_v += a1_a;
  a2_v += a2_a;
  a1 += a1_v;
  a2 += a2_v;

  // a1_v *= 0.99;
  // a2_v *= 0.99;

  canvas.beginDraw();
  //canvas.background(0, 1);
  canvas.translate(cx, cy);
  canvas.stroke(0);
  if (frameCount > 1) {
    canvas.line(px2, py2, x2, y2);
   }
  canvas.endDraw();


  px2 = x2;
  py2 = y2;
}
```

Comment: didn't you mean `Java` instead of `Javascript`? They are (absolutely) not the same

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Henry I need to rework the physics so that the mousepressed function moves the second pendulum realistically. At the moment it puts the second circle at the mouse position regardless of the value of r2 (it should stay at 200 like a metal rod or something but on mouse press it changes like a variable and acts like a piece of rubber). Also the simulation continues as if the second circle was never moved but it should The mousepressed function should take into account the length of r1 and r2 and make the second circle the mouse position using the straight lines of the pendulum.

Comment: How about you use the mouse position as a gravity source and add a corresponding force term to all objects as long as the button is pressed?

Comment: @LutzL Would it work by changing the value of the gravity variable i already have or using a different variable entirely? Also how would it impact the circles without affecting anything else in the pendulum. I only want the moving parts to be affected, things like the starting point and lines between the circles shouldnt move